# What are the commands for using Git Bash in Windows e.g. when in git diff mode?

Tags: windows, git, bash

In Windows, in Git Bash, if I do a git diff I get all the differences flushed to the console with some sort of prompt to control the output buffer. What are the commands I can use in this mode of Git Bash? I don't know where to look for a quick reference.

I've worked out that `<Enter>` will scroll one line, and `<Space>` will scroll all lines, but not much more than that. To quit I do a Ctrl-C, which seems to go back to a command prompt, but then sometimes when I start typing a new command it seems to go back to the unfinished diff output and I'm confused as to why.

Really dumb question, I know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git diff` pipes the diff file into the Unix [`less`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29) pager. Press `h` when the diff view is open to see a bunch of commands. The particularly important ones to know:

- `h` - Display help/commands
- `q` - Quit/close
- `[Space]` scroll 'k' lines ahead, where k should default to your terminal's line display height.
- `[Enter]` scroll 'k' lines ahead, where k defaults to 1